# How to specify .apk file which is generated by latest building

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I want to manipulate apk file after build.

But I can't find a way to specify the apk which is generated by latest building.

(There are many apk files in /build/outputs/apk dir.)

I'm using AndroidStudio.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate apk file after build"?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I want to replace icon files in apk :)

Comment: Why don't you replace them in the `res` files before building your APK?

Comment: Well GeniusQ has already mentioned how the name can be changed. But what I understand from your question is that  you are looking to find the exact apk that has been created from the latest build. Well some basics can be like timestamp, another could be just delete all of them and build and you would have only the latest in the folder ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change generated APK name, add this code to **app/build.gradle** file to specify the APK by version name define in `defaultConfig` or anything you want (Eg: timestamp,..)

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(
                      output.outputFile.parent,
                                output.outputFile.name.replace("project_name", "app${variant.versionName}"))
           }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your desire app icon(preferably *.png) in the **drawable** folder and then open your **AndroidManifest** file. Go to Application tab and change your app icon. Now build your app. That should work.